# Place text besides div

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to transform XML into HTML. In the below code, I am trying to display the width of the bar at the end of the bar i.e right side. But due to the div tag used to create the bar, the value is moving to the next line as shown in the attached graphic. Please help in placing it towards right.

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/price">
Current node:
<xsl:variable name="maxbars" select="."/>
<div style="width: {$maxbars}%; height: 18px; background-color: blue"></div>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<br>
</xsl:for-each>


<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
```

[image]

Comment: There's no graphic.  You should have the CSS be external.  You'd probably need to add `display:inline` or `float` depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: also if you're actually looking to work with XSLT you should be applying a template rather than using `for-each` for this type of transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `float:left` for the DIV and remove `<br>` -

```
<div style="width: {$maxbars}%; height: 18px; background-color: blue; float: left;"></div>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>

</xsl:for-each>


<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
```

Comment: `<br>` should at least be `<br/>`.  If that tag is removed there should be an additional block element wrapped around the iteration.